# Stumped on simple Jquery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been stuck with this for hours trying different ways of implementing it. I don't understand why it wont work. 
I am trying toggle a ul between show/hide whenever a button is clicked, but it will not work.
Here is the relevant code:

In the head:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The Code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.active-stream').live('click', function(event) {        
        jQuery('.feed-list').toggle('show');
        });
    });
</script>

<button type="button" class="active-stream">Click Me!</button>

<ul class="feed-list">
<li>feed 1</li>
<li>feed 2</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you adding `.active-stream` buttons dynamically? If not, you don't need to use `.live` or delegation, you can just use normal event binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is deprecated as of 1.7 and removed as of 1.9. Use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead..

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NB62T/1/)**
Use this,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('click','.active-stream', function(event) {        
        jQuery('.feed-list').toggle('slow');   //use 'slow'
    });
});
```

Also, to add the functionality of `.live()`, you need to use delegation (Only if you are adding elements dynamically.)

Comment: To duplicate what `.live` does, you need to use the delegation syntax of `.on`.

Comment: that works as long as there are no buttons added after the dom is ready. otherwise he needs to change it into something like `jQuery('body').on('click', '.active-stream',function(event) {  ` or some parent element selector instead of `body`

Comment: Your comment popped after I submitted mine, didn't mean to duplicate it

Comment: I did not see any dynamic addition in the code, but still, for the correctness of it, you both are right here.

Comment: I changed my code to what shaunakde shared and still no luck.. I don't understand why it wont work..

Comment: check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/NB62T/1/ I think your version should be 1.11.0

Comment: Thank you all very much! Got it running in 11.1. I can rest easy knowing that headache is finally over.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your jQuery Library to this :
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

and Your script will be :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.active-stream').on('click', function(event) {        
        jQuery('.feed-list').toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

That shall work.. Cheers :)

Comment: I checked that and the version(1.11) is not working with .on() .. So I tested that with 1.9.1 and it is working. So i just gave my answer. Its upon him whether he uses that or not. Also If I am using 1.11 then I get "jQuery is not defined" error in console.